# What's the NXDOMAIN meaning of nslookup?

Tags: domain, nslookup

I use nslookup to check a domain's IP address:

```
dele-MBP:~ dele$ nslookup www.ts111.com
Server:     192.168.2.1
Address:    192.168.2.1#53

** server can't find www.ts111.com: NXDOMAIN
```

but what's the `NXDOMAIN` meaning?

Comment: It stands for **N**on-e**X**istent **Domain**. So your `nslookup` is returning no results for that address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @n8te already commented, it stands for **N**on-e**X**istent **Domain**.

Technically, `NXDOMAIN` is a valid response to a DNS query, not an error. It just happens to be a negative response: "no, the specific thing you asked for doesn't exist". Nothing ambiguous about it, case closed, end of discussion. It does **not** mean the resolver library should retry the query with another DNS server.

Such a negative response can even be cached, although the lifetime of negative responses in a DNS cache is usually set to be fairly short.